# How to change my android application's theme?

Tags: android, themes

How can i change theme of my app.Buttons and other things are in an ordinary look.i just want to change those ordinary look.

Comment: Do you want to change app's theme or button's theme?

Comment: are you wishing to customise your buttons? just change the background of the button or view from your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

Use appcompat in your app, it gives some of the good things from lollipop to all pre-lollipop supported apps. http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html
I have mimicked complete material design using appcompat.

Widgets supported by appcompat are:

- EditText
- Spinner
- CheckBox
- RadioButton
- Switch (use the new android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat)
- CheckedTextView

For styling button use the below style:

```
<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">88dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">36dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:translationZ">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/primary_round</item>
</style>
```

Also you can use this library to prep up your app with material design, https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Answer (score 0):

To  change button style, you can change its background. Here is an example for you. Follow these steps:

**1. Define button background**

For example:

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background" // this is your button background
        android:text="@string/myButton"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

**2. Create a new folder in `res` folder**

Right click on res folder in your project **>** New **>** Folder. Name it with `drawable`.

**3. Create a new `xml` file for your button background**

Here, we can name it with `button_background.xml`. You may rename it later. Place it in drawable folder. So, fill it with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- view background color-->
    <solid android:color="@color/your_background_color" >
    </solid>

    <!-- If you want to add some padding -->
    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />

    <!-- Here is the corner radius -->
    <corners
        android:radius="6dp"   >
    </corners>

</shape>
```

And, completed... For information about changing app's theme, this is a reference for you: [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)